# Wicket circular detach issue

Tags: wicket

I have a composite type of model for my table.

- The table model contains several row models as member variable.
- Each row model gets the table model passed in the constructor and stores it as member variable.

Now the problem comes up when I need to detach the models. In my table model I need to call detach for each of the row models. And in each row model I need to detach the table model. This obviously leads in circular detaching and eventual stack overflow.

How can I properly detach the models with this design?

Comment: Why do you need to detach the models manually?

Comment: Do not detach parent model from detach () method of IModel  implentation. If you need to detach, invoke detaching from a Component's method or from an event listener to prevent cyclic detaching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned, you should use Component's onDetach() to detach your models. Then you should be able to avoid cyclic detaching easily.